# What does coefficients means in positive semi definite matrix definition

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, positive-semidefinite

The "positive semi-definiteness" definition of a Matrix $K$ may be formulated as follows:

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n c_i c_j K_{i,j} \ge 0 \equiv c^T K c \ge 0$$

for any $c_1, ... , c_n \in \Bbb{R}$

But I can't figure out what do the coefficients $c_1, ..., c_n$ add to the definition. One told me they are used for the $=$ par of the $\ge$ when $c_1, ..., c_n$ are all equals to zero but without certainty.

Comment: It's much more clear to say that $K$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $c^T K c \geq 0$ for all vectors $c \in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I agree. But I've not seen this notation so far. Nevertheless, I still don't understand what it is the point of this vector c.

Comment: The matrix $K$ is used to define a function $\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any matrix $K$, we define the quadratic form associated with $K$ to be the function $q:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
q(c) = q(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n) = \sum_{ij}K_{ij}c_ic_j
$$
The vector $c$ here is an input to a function; it's just like the $x$ in $f(x) = x^2$.  We say that $K$ is positive semidefinite if $q(c) \geq 0$ for every possible $c$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understand that but if $(1)~\sum_{ij} K_{ij} c_i cj \ge 0$ then $(2)~\sum_{ij} K_{ij} \ge 0$, right?  (just take the vector $c$ composed of 1s). So why do we need to say it works with every vector $c$? Is there an exemple of symetric Matrix which verify $(2)$ but not $(1)$ ??

Comment: Yes there is! For example: take
$$
K = \pmatrix{1&2\\2&1}, \qquad c = (1,-1)
$$